# how we can find the connexion of importrange function sources in ActiveSpreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

there are some sheets in my spreadsheet and I want find how many times I use importrange function to know every connection in my active spreadsheet.
Is there a formula to find this values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count importrange in all of the sheets in a spreadsheet.

```
function countImportRange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const n = ss.getSheets().reduce((a,sh,i) => {
    a += sh.getValues().flat().filter(e => e.toString().toLowerCase().includes('importrange')).filter(e => e).length;
    return a;
  },0);
  Logger.log(n);
}
```

- [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)